# Azure Method not allowed when trying to Post trough AzureMobileServices SDK

Tags: .net, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using Xamarin and the MobileServices SDK for my client side app, and Azure with .Net backend. 
I implemented an ApiController , and i can successfully retrieve data when making a GET cal trough the sdk.
Here is the Get Code :

```
public async Task<UserData> Get()
    {
        UserData newData = new UserData();
        newData.name = "null";
        ..shortened..
        return newData;
    }
```

I implemented a POST method too:

```
public async Task<UserData> Post(string ownerId)
    {
        UserData newData = new UserData();
        newData.ownerId = ownerId;
        var success = false;
        ..shortened...
        return success;
    }
```

And i can successfully call it via Postman, but the sdk throws me this error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:
>   The request could not be completed.  (Method Not Allowed )

here is the client side code :
GET Call:

```
var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync<UserData>("userData",System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

POST Call

```
var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync<UserData, bool>("userData", ownerId, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, null);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post some simplified code and fiddler output of the failed request?

Comment: I added the code of the backend and client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can call the SDK successfully via Postman, then the problem must be with your `InvokeApiAsync` call. You can log the client HTTP request in one of two ways:

- Add a DelegatingHandler to your client and log outgoing calls. See [Log outgoing requests (Windows, Xamarin)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#managed-client-xamarin-windows).
- Use Fiddler to [Capture Traffic from iOS Device](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS#capture-traffic-from-ios-device) or [Configure Fiddler for Android](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid#configure-fiddler-for-android--google-nexus-7).

Also, make sure that you are using the `[MobileAppController]` attribute in your API controller class. See [How to: Define a custom API controller](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller).

Comment: Thanks, i have implemented the LoggingHandler how. I found that when doing the post request throug postman, the name of the parameter has to match the backends method input name. When I check the request  I can see this : `Request: POST https://api.near.lu/api/userData
passedValue` , can I specify somehow how the parameter is called ?

Comment: If you need a JSON payload, you should create a JObject and assign the value. E.g. `JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new fieldName = ownerId)`. See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm.

Comment: I am not sure if i do need it, i just want to get it working? What is the general procedure in implementing a Post method that accepts a paramter ? Or the other way around, what is wrong in my example above ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. On Postman, I assume you're using a JSON payload in order to set the parameter name. If not, are you using form-data for the payload?

Comment: So on Postman i am sending this link as POST request :  https://api.near.lu/api/userdata?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0&ownerId=1234 and i am getting 'true' as reply. what is bothering me is that i have another apicontroller implemented in a different file and there post works without a problem. But them again there the post is the only implemented control... If it helps any?

Comment: Your API controller might not be configured properly. In Postman, you are not sending a body at all, you are sending a query string. You can add the query string using the overload of `InvokeApiAsync` that has a requestHeaders parameter. There you can specify the name of the query parameter. To learn more about parameter binding on the server, see [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Ok thanks for that usefull link! It is probably that the backend is expectimg the simple type to be passed over the uri, and the mobileservices sdk passes it through the body and this confuses the controller ! I will try it out  thanks!

Comment: Ok thank you alot that did the trick ! So for those who encounter this problem, the client SDK sends all parameters as body, but the backend expects simple types like int, string etc. as URi. So you need to specify in the backend that the parameter comes as body  by adding the [FromBody] tag like so : `public async Task<bool> Post([FromBody]string parameter)
        { ... }`